# Regex matching groups by prefix

Tags: regex

I'm having the following string: **CL_6x CL_5c CL_234 CL_ERB14 1D CL_6y**

I need to find a regex to extract groups like this

- CL_6x
- CL_5c
- CL_234
- CL_ERB14 1D
- CL_6y

As you can see they're all prefixed with **CL_**

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a positive lookahead based regex.

```
\bCL_.*?(?=\s*CL_|$)
```

This should match until the next `CL_` or end of the line.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iO5rI1/1)

Comment: This is the only one that actually works of all the answers.

Comment: Who's first, Avinash with 100k or [ten millionth question on SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299058/lets-predict-the-date-of-the-ten-millionth-question-on-stack-overflow) :D

Comment: You wouldn't find a CL_ that isn't followed by another CL_ though (or end of string).  That happens to be the case for his string, but maybe that's not what he's asking.

Comment: @Jonny5 Ya, I'm going to hit 100k today itself.. What's that link? let me check.

Answer (score 2):

```
CL_.+?\b
```

Try this.See demo.`\b` is `word boundary`

https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/86

EDIT:

for test cases like `CL_ERB14 1D`.

use

```
CL_\S+(?:\s*(?!CL_)\S+)
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/87

Comment: This won't match `CL_ERB14 1D`

Answer (score 1):

You can use following regex.

```
^CL_.+\b
```

**Explanation**

1. `^`: Starts with
2. `CL_`: Matches literal `CL_`
3. `.+`: Matches any characters any number of times
4. `\b`: Word boundary

[image]

Comment: This matches anything following CL_.  Maybe he wants to match each individual code, and not the entire string...

Comment: Ok, that's better, but it still doesn't match those which contain spaces.